# How to execute an updated "start" attribute in "package.json" instead of the original one using "npm start"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm totally new at React, I'm trying to learn that language using a book that starts by teaching the basics of node (and npm).

The author teaches how to create a simple server, and how to execute it using `npm start`; here is the code.

> **server.js**

```
require("http").createServer((inRequest, inResponse) => 
{ 
    inResponse.end("My first server");
}).listen(8011);
```

> **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ServerFirst",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "start": "node server.js"
}
```

executing `npm start` runs `server.js` alright.

---

Adding the `request` module is what I did next so the new `server_time.js` script obtains a json file with eastern standard time.

> **server_time.js**

```
require("http").createServer((inRequest, inResponse) => 
{ 
    const requestModule = require("request");
    requestModule(
        "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now", 
        function(inErr, inResp, inBody)
        {
            inResponse.end(`My first server: ${inBody}`);
        }
    );
}).listen(8011);
```

Then, I modified `package.json` to start with `server_time.js` instead of starting with `server.js`

> **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ServerFirst",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "start": "node server_time.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```

when I execute `npm start` the terminal prints the same as before except for the version which now is 1.0.1, and when I check in my browser it runs `server.js` and not the script I want:

```
ServerFirst@1.0.1 start ~\ServerFirst
node server.js
```

why is `npm start` running `node server.js` instead of `node server_time.js`? it obviously can tell that the `version` attribute changed, but not the `start` attribute.

Note that `node server_time.js` works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the second "start" script into the `scripts` block:

```
{
  "name": "ServerFirst",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start-time": "node server_time.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```

Name it whatever you want, then run `npm run start-time` (in this example).

Comment: Nice! it works just fine with `npm run`, the whole point was to just modify the `package.json` so I wouldn't have to type the script name.

Comment: You have to type `run` for custom scripts. You can see all the commands by typing `npm help`. Also see the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for how they work.